# Adding step size to cross validation in Python package lifelines

Tags: python

I'm using the Python package *lifelines* to build a CoxPH model where I reduce the step size to 0.1, like so:

```
cph = CoxPHFitter()
cph.fit(df, 'time', 'event', fit_options = {"step_size":0.1})
```

I used k_fold_cross_validation to build the model, but I don't know how to add in step size. I expected to add it to fitter_kwargs, like this, but this does not work:

```
k_fold_cross_validation(cph, df, duration_col='time', event_col='event', k=5, fitter_kwargs={fit_options:{"step_size":0.1}})
```

Comment: have you tried simply cph.fit(df, 'time', 'event', step_size=0.1} ?

Comment: @JRodrigoF I wouldn't be able to do cross-validation then